# What is simpliest way to get Line number and position no in regex matches charcter?

Tags: c#

When I have a match, obtained using the `Regex` class, how do I find the matching line number and position in that line, of the match, like Notepad++ does?

Example:

```
void Main()
{
    string _strText = @"Line 1
Line 2
Line 3";
    var re = new Regex("2");
    var m = re.Match(_strText);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Index); // outputs 13
                                    // 13 -> line 2, position 6?
    }
}
```

Comment: So if this works, what is your question?

Comment: If you want to share some helpful code you wrote or found, you can post a self-answered question. The question must still be a unique, on-topic question though, and the answer must be posted as an answer. Please read [ask] and [answer].

Comment: It is very good of you wanting to contribute to the wast amount of information on Stack Overflow. I also did a cursory search and there doesn't seem to be an immediate search result for how to obtain this information so this might indeed be a unique and useful question with an answer. However, please be aware that Stack Overflow is a Q&A site with the two things separate. In other words, when posting a question, post it as a question. Then, afterwards, you can provide an answer to the same question, but you should make it separate.

Comment: So I would edit your question to be like a question, and state the problem, that you want to know the position in the document of a match of a regex search, getting both line number and position in that line, and then ask how this can be done? And then you can provide an answer where you post those lines of code. But as @CodeCaster stated, please read [ask] and [answer] first to make sure you post a good question and a good answer.

Comment: I want to get line no like 2 and col: like 5 in your example
when i use your code for find character '2'

Comment: This is a self answer question...!!

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule And...? It is perfectly legal and in fact encouraged to post questions you already know the answer to provided that 1) It can posted in a Q&A format, 2) It is not already covered by existing questions and answers and 3) It holds some general interest. Other than perhaps a more exhaustive search for duplicates here (which initially I could not find), I think this question and answer fits all 3, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get matching line no:

```
 long lineNumber = _strText.Substring(0, m.Index).LongCount(chr => chr == '\n') + 1;
```

and get spacific charcter position in this line:

```
int fis = _strText.LastIndexOf("\n", m.Index);
                    int posi = m.Index - fis;
```

here posi is the col position 
this code very helpful for get matching character line no and in this line col no like visual studio editor

Comment: I have edited in some code in your question. One thing I have to say though is that you're doing re-searches in the line, I think that may be both unnecessary as well as errorprone, though I can't put my finger on exactly what could go wrong here. You could also use some more descriptive names in your code, as lis, fis, not sure what these does to be honest.

Comment: I think you don't need the `lis` variable, isn't that the same as `m.Index`? Also, what if the match is on the first line? `fis`, what value will this have then?

Comment: In this code you found output like line no:2 and column no in specific line is:5

Comment: lis is use to find the expect location of character and this is not same as m.index

Comment: You sure about that? I tested with m.Index and it seems to find the same value very time.